# Widget with search facility in wxwidgets

Tags: user-interface, search, wxwidgets

I was wondering if there were any nice widgets in wxwidgets, with search ability. I mean searching for data in large tables like, data in wxgrid.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be slow and inefficient in several ways to store all of a large dataset in wxGrid, and then to search through wxGrid.

It would be better to keep the dataset in a database and use the database engine to search through it.  wxGrid need only store the data that is visible in the GUI.

Here is some high level pseudo code of how this works.

- Load data into store.  The store should probably be a database, but it might be a vector or any STL container.  Even a text file could be made to work!
- Set current viewable row to a sensible value.  I am assuming your data is arranged in rows
- Load rows including and around current into wxGrid.
- User enters search term
- Send search request to data store, which returns row containing target
- Set current row to row containing target
- Load rows including and around current into wxGrid.

Comment: I need to display data, and enable the user to search through that data. Can anyone please tell, how it can be done, with wxwidgets?

Comment: @jvc Displaying data and searching data are two different functions.  It makes no sense to use the display code ( wxWidgets ) to search the data.  Searching is done using the code that stores the data.

Comment: @jvc Added some detail to my answer explaining how to search a data store and display the results in wxGrid